# Решаю задачу на Codeforses, не могу понять почему не проходит претесты

Tags: java, олимпиада

Есть мысли, что не так? Идеи по улучшению кода тоже принимаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TaskB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scn.nextLine();
        int left = 10000000;
        int right = 0;
        int max = str.indexOf("(");
        while(left>max){
            left = str.lastIndexOf('(',left-1);
            right = str.indexOf(")");
            String subs = str.substring(left+1,right);
            Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
            Matcher matcher1= pattern1.matcher(subs);
            Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+|[a-z]+|\\D+");
            Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(subs);
            int count=1;
            String dop="0";
            while(matcher1.find()) {
                 count = Integer.parseInt(matcher1.group());

            }
            while(matcher2.find()) {
                 dop =matcher2.group();

            }
            subs="";
            for(int x=0;x<count;x++){
                subs+=dop;
            }


            str = str.substring(0,left)+subs+str.substring(right+1);
        }
        System.out.println(str);


    }
}
```

Comment: проверьте `"(2a)(3b)"`

Comment: Скобки надо через стек разруливать)

Comment: @IR42 большое спасибо, ошибку понял, пошел исправлять

Comment: @vp_arth  не могли бы вы объяснить подребнее?

Comment: Увидел открытую скобку, положил текущую работу в стек(ну или функцию вызвал от остатка строки) Увидел закрытую, можно возвращаться к тому, что в стеке) Между скобками работаешь, как в первый раз)